# Manage load and timeout on couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I have a couchbase cluster with 4 hosts (4 CPU, 32 GB ram).

This cluster is used by thousands processes which get data from it. I have 8K permanent connections on the cluster (data from couchbase ui).

The bandwidth uses by couchbase is 50MB/s per hosts to send data (don't seem very heavy).

But I get client side timeout. About 4 per seconds and I don't understand why.

I set somaxconn and tcp_syn_backlog to 2048 per hosts but it doesn't change something.

Do you have any idea ?

**Edit from comments:**

I have this kind of logs from my client:

> Error from Couchbase, passing in non-blocking mode (EXC:
>   Key=u'fieldmetadata', RC=0x17[Client-Side timeout
>   exceeded for operation. Inspect network conditions or increase the
>   timeout], Operational Error, Results=1, C
>   Source=(src/multiresult.c,316), Tracing
>   Output={"fieldmetadata": {"i": 15890195098182236653,
>   "s": "kv:Unknown", "b": "MetaDataV3", "r":
>   "ltg-aus-couchbase-3:11210", "t": 2500000}}>)

I have 3 nodes in my cluster. All clients and cluster is on Azure VM.

Comment: What language and which version of Couchbase Server and the SDK are you using?  Can you post debug logs from the application?

Comment: FWIW, if it's Java...a) upgrade the SDk and b) check for garbage collection pauses.  Those are the two most common solutions to timeouts.  Not saying there aren't others, just easy to rule those out.

Comment: It's used with python. Couchbase 5.5 server and couchbase==2.5.8 for python

Comment: Okay, we'll still need a bit more information to help debug...do you have logs from the client?  Also make sure you're re-using the same client object as much as possible across multiple threads rather than constantly creating and destroying it.  Which python framework are you using?  Also, 8k connections isn't indicative of a problem by itself, but does that match with how many application instances you have?

Comment: Timeouts can be either client, network or server...a quick way of ruling it out is to take a packet capture and look for the request that times out.  How long does it take to get to the server, how long does it take to respond, etc.  If it goes to the server and then doesn't come back for a long time, we can investigate the server performance...if it goes to the server and comes back quickly, we can investigate the SDK/application.

Comment: Also, what is the infrastructure of the client and server: physical hardware, vm, cloud, container (if container...on physical, vm, cloud?)

Comment: I edit my question with logs and platform. I have thousands processes which don't create thread (historic from the company :( ) so I have thousand client objects

Answer (score 0):

Kiva, as per [a similar thread on the couchbase forums](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbaseerror-client-side-timeout-exceeded-for-operation/3396/4)

Can you set LCB_LOGLEVEL=5 in your environment (i.e. as an environment variable) and re-run the code? ... which may help reveal more information as to why it’s timing out.